# Django - Why does this TableView has two paginators?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, tableview

In my Django project I have a view that has two paginators, and I can't identify where each of them comes from. They look like this:
[image]

I want to delete one of them, but I realized they are not working the same way.

**The one above to the right** always paginates 25 results (10 on the first, 10 on the second and 5 on the third page.

**The one below** seems to be dividing the whole queryset in sets of 25, which then the other paginator iterates over.

So, for example, if I have 100 rows, the **paginator below** says there's 4 pages. If I select the number 2 in that paginator, the **paginator on the right** iterates over those 25 rows, and not the whole queryset.

My view looks like this:

```
class ClientTableView(AdminPermissionsMixin, PagedFilteredTableView):
    model = Client
    table_class = ClientTable
    template_name = 'users/client/client_table.html'
    filter_class = ClientFilter
    formhelper_class = ClientFormHelper
    exclude_columns = ('actions',)
    export_name = 'regiones'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientTableView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['allows_user_creation'] = self.request.user.users_permission == '2'
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ClientTableView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(allows_credit=False)
        return qs
```

The template `client_table.html` looks like this:

```
{% extends "table.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block users_active %}active{% endblock %}
{% block page_title %}Clientes{% endblock page_title %}

{% block table_title %}Lista de clientes{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item accordion active"><a href="{% url "users" %}">Lista de clientes</a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block table_actions %}
    <a href="{% url "credit_client_list" %}" class="mb-sm btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px">Clientes
        cartera</a>
    {% if allows_user_creation %}
        <a href="{% url "create_client" %}" class="mb-sm btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Agregar cliente</a>
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static "js/table-spanish.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And `table.html` looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_tables2 crispy_forms_tags staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="card card-custom gutter-b">
        <div class="card-header flex-wrap py-3">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h3 class="card-label">
                    <i class="fas {% block table_icon %}fa-list-alt{% endblock %}"></i>
                    {% block table_title %}{% endblock %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-toolbar">
                {% block table_actions %}
                    {% if object_list|length > 0 %}
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline ml-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bolder dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-export"></i>Exportar
                            </button>
                            <!--begin::Dropdown Menu-->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right" style="">
                                <!--begin::Navigation-->
                                <ul class="navi flex-column navi-hover py-2">
                                    <li class="navi-header font-weight-bolder text-uppercase font-size-sm text-primary pb-2">
                                        Elige una opción:
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navi-item">
                                        <a href="{% url 'export_pdf' "local" %}" class="navi-link">
                        <span class="navi-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i>
                        </span>
                                            <span class="navi-text">PDF</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="navi-item">
                                        <a href="{% url 'export_xlsx' "local" %}" class="navi-link">
                        <span class="navi-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-file-excel"></i>
                        </span>
                                            <span class="navi-text">XLSX</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!--end::Navigation-->
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Dropdown Menu-->
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            {% block table_statistics %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% block body_table %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 mb-5">
                        <div id="datatable1_filter" class="dataTables_length">
                            {% crispy filter.form %}
{#                            <label>Buscar:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0"></label>#}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="{% block url_table_actions %}{% endblock %}" method="post" id="action">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% block table %}
                        {% render_table table "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html" %}
                    {% endblock %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="command" id="command"/>
                </form>
            {% endblock %}
            {% block table_bottom %}
            {% endblock table_bottom %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
{#    <script src="{% static "js/datatables.bundle.js" %}"></script>#}
    <script src="{% static "js/basic.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**WHAT I KNOW**

I identified that the **paginator on the right**, is added by the line `<script src="{% static "js/table-spanish.js" %}"></script>` in `client_table.html`, and if I remove that line, that paginator disappears, and the other one iterates correctly over the whole queryset.

However, I would really like to keep that line, since it also gives me other functionalities which I'd rather keep simple.

I'd like to identify what line or library could be responsible for the other paginator, **the one below** and, if possible, delete that one instead and let the **paginator on the right** iterate over the whole queryset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right side pagination is datatables.js and the lower pagination is from Django-tables2. Django-tables2 is going to give you pagination for that by default, you can easily disable it.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pagination.html#disabling-pagination

Just add `table_pagination = False`

```
class ClientTableView(AdminPermissionsMixin, PagedFilteredTableView):
    table_pagination = False
```

(django-filters' `PagedFilteredTableView` inherits from django-tables2' `SingleTableView`)